# AJAX return empty results from POST method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can't receive data from AJAX request in my ajax.php file:

Here my AJAX request

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'src/ajax.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(response);
        }

    };
    
    var test = { data: "test",};

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(test));
});
```

And here the ajax.php :

```
    echo json_encode($_POST['test']);
```

I choose to not use jQuery by the way because I don't want to.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: What is in `$_POST` when you check? Anything at all?

Comment: Try looking at `$_POST['data']` because thats what you called the variable in `var test = { data: "test",};`

Comment: @RiggsFolly except they JSON stringified it, so it won't be in $_POST...

Comment: Trying to `json_encode` something which is already JSON makes no sense (even if you were trying to read it from the correct place). You'd need to _decode_ it.

Comment: @ADyson Ahh missed that

Comment: @RiggsFolly that would just send the text "[object Object]" to the server as a string (see https://jsfiddle.net/082bjhwr/). XHR isn't as clever as newer AJAX libraries...OP would need to build their own form-url-encoded string first, and pass it in. And also remove the content-type header.

Comment: I wrote an SQL request and I used console.log to display the results and it works.

The problem I'm facing is I would like to pass a var to this SQL request in my JSON object but $_POST always returns empty array. It's like the ajax.js is not allowed to send data to the ajax.php

Comment: Php does not put json data into $_POST. Read the duplicate, please

Answer (score -1):

if you are sending

```
{data: "test"}
```

i guess in your php should be the code like this

```
echo json_encode($_POST)
```

or

```
echo $_POST['data']
```

cause there is no param named `test` in your request

Comment: There's no `POST` param named `data` either. Read the duplicate (in the blue box at the top, if you refresh your page)